# Solr connection timeout during indexing?

Tags: solr, indexing, timeout, connection-timeout, solr4

I have solrj client with infinite timeout(Solr4)

```
server.server.setSoTimeout(0)
server.server.setConnectionTimeout(0)
```

When I index my data I have many timeouts on server side.
Where can I update server side timeouts in solrconfig.xml or possible tomcat config?

Client side exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
```

Server side exception:

```
 Jan 31, 2013 8:55:54 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
    SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Read timed out
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:159)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1699)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:751)
```

Comment: did you end up resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with *Solr 4*. We solved this after reading a [blog post by Uwe Schindler](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html) (a *Solr* commiter).

With *Solr 4* and several *Solr 3* versions, you have to let an important share of your RAM free so that the system can use properly the [*mmap* system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap). This can be subtle depending on your system configuration (the blog post gives a plenty of informations on that point). In our case, this solved the problem: we could finally index without any more *timeout* issue.

Answer (score -1):

the info for tomcat server.xml config will solve this. we got same stack trace and the below solved it for us:
http://forums.alfresco.com/ja/node/8458